# How do I call a print function in other functions in C?

Tags: c, linux

I have to call for one printf function for X number of different functions. I am struggling to call the printf function from the returnString function in the other two functions. I am new to C and I am used to Java so I am not sure how to fix this. This is what I have tried:

```
char returnString(double a, double b, double c, double x, double y) {
    char str[] = "time = %f, distance = %f, passengers = %f, value = %f, value = %f", a, b, c, x, y;
    printf("%s", str);
    return str[];
}

double findTime(double b, double c, double x, double y) {
    double a;
    a = 50;
    printf(returnString);
    return a;
}

double findDistance(double a, double c, double x, double y) {
    double b;
    b = 30;
    return b;
}
```

Comment: I think you want `sprintf()`

Comment: Your confusion is due to the fact that Java has a mechanism, based on C's `printf` function, which is much more general that C's `printf` function.  Barmar's right, you want `sprintf`, but you're also going to have to learn about string allocation, because C does **not** do that for you automatically.

Comment: You can't `return str[];` *[sic]*. The caller can supply a buffer and its size. Or allocate a buffer dynamically and return a pointer to it (for the caller to `free`). Or use a `static` buffer which is not thread safe.

Comment: You essentially *can't* have a function that constructs and returns a string in C, which is what your `returnString` function is trying to do.  There are several ways of simulating such a function, but they're all at least mildly cumbersome, meaning that most of the time, C programmers don't even try to write functions that act like they construct and return strings.

Comment: For now, in `findTime`, you could just call something like `printf("time = %f, distance = %f, passengers = %f, value = %f\n", b, c, x, y);`.  If that's not what you want, tell us what's wrong with it, and we can probably suggest other alternatives.

Comment: The problem is that for the assignment, we're only allowed to use one printf function in the entire C file and one per function. Would sprintf allow for the same format as the printf above? The other issue I am having is that the parameters for the other functions are slightly different with the values but the format of the print has to be the same.

Comment: `sprintf` uses exactly the same formats as `printf` and takes an additional buffer argument. If you use `snprintf` it also needs a buffer size.

Comment: I think you need to start from the C book. Basically, you do not have even a basic C knowledge. What is `char str[] = "time = %f, distance = %f, passengers = %f, value = %f, value = %f", a, b, c, x, y;`?

Comment: I second @0___________. The code is so confused and ungrammatical that it is even hard to see what you are trying to do. You need to get a grip of the basics first. Weather Vane's remarks, as usual, are right: You cannot return arrays from functions. Nothing in C survives its scope (between `{` and `}`) unless it's been `malloc()`ed. I wish i could say that any resemblance of C and Java is accidental and unintentional; alas, the similarity is by design but utterly deceptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocating the string buffer in `main()` as a local variable and passing its address to the `returnString()` function would work and you do not have to be bothered by freeing the memory occupied by the `OutputStr[]` because the storage of local variables is freed automatically when the function ends.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

char* returnString(char* OutputStr, double a, double b, double c, double x, double y) {
    sprintf(OutputStr, "time = %f, distance = %f, passengers = %f, value = %f, value = %f", a, b, c, x, y);
    return OutputStr;
}

double findTime(double b, double c, double x, double y) {
    double a;
    a = 50;
    return a;
}

double findDistance(double a, double c, double x, double y) {
    double b;
    b = 30;
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    char OutputStr[1024];

    printf ("%s \n %f \n %f \n", returnString(OutputStr, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0), findTime(6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0), findDistance(10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0));
    return 0;
}
```

Of course this begs for buffer overflow if the string returned by the `returnString()` is longer than 1023 characters,  so don't use this in a production code.
Also, allocating large variables on the stack is not a good practice, but 1024 bytes will not break anything nowadays.

In another solution it would be possible to dynamically allocate the memory for the output string ( e.g. by `malloc()` ) **inside** of the function `returnString()` and return the address of this memory from this function, but then you would have to remember to free this memory in `main()`.  If you forgot then a memory leak would result, because in C there is no garbage collector to hold your hand.
*Offtopic: In C++ you could use a smart pointer to do this automatically but C++ STL already has a `string` class that does it for you.*

Comment: How would I call for the returnString function inside the findTime and findDistance? We're not allowed a main method either since that's given to us.

Comment: Where do you want to call `printf()` if not in `main()` ?

Comment: I can only use one printf, I need to call it in the other functions like findTime and findDistance. The main method is already given to us.

Comment: From the inside of the findTime() function you can call it like this: `printf ("%s \n %f \n %f \n", returnString(OutputStr, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0), a, findDistance(10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0) );` but you have to add the `char OutputStr[1024];` declaration inside the `findTime()` function before you call the `printf()` and `returnString()` function. Don't forget to upvote my answer with the gray triangle.

Comment: Do you have any other questions ?